# Use angularjs expression bindings with downgraded angular

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-upgrade

Say i have a checkbox directive i'm rewriting to angular from angularjs

*checkbox.directive.js (angularjs)*

```
template: `<some html> ...`,
scope: { checked: '=', onChecked: '&' }
```

*checkbox.component.ts (angular)*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox',
  templateUrl: '<some html> ...',
  ...
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() checked: boolean;
  @Output() checkedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() onCheckedChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  ...
```

**How can i bind to the expression binding (&) from not yet upgraded components?**

*not-yet-upgraded.directive.js (angularjs)*

```
template: '<checkbox (onChecked)="foo()"> ...',
controller: function($scope) { 
   $scope.foo = function() { console.log("change happened"); }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, I had two mistakes

1. Outputs of events doesn't need the `Change`-suffix unless it's a two-way binding
2. The angularjs consumer uses kebab-casing

so:

1.
`angular component` @Output() onChecked<s>Change</s> = new EventEmitter();

2.
`angularjs dom` <checkbox (on-checked)="foo()"> ...